# Meteor: Calling/triggering events from inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an event that looks like this:

```
Template.foo.events({
    'bar': function() {
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
});
```

How do I call/trigger it from within the client using JS? Something like:

```
qwe = new Event(foo);
qwe.dispatchEvent();?
```

Comment: The [CustomEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) (MDN link) could help.

Answer (score 0):

See events in the Meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-events

> "The first part of the key (before the first space) is the name of the
>   event being captured. Pretty much any DOM event is supported. Some
>   common ones are: click, mousedown, mouseup, mouseenter, mouseleave,
>   keydown, keyup, keypress, focus, blur, and change."

So in your example, 'bar' should be replaced with something like 'click'. This even would then be fired when your template is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should associate your event type to a CSS selector so you'll be able to reference the targeted HTML element later in order to actually trigger the event programmatically.

By default, when you don't specify a target element, the event will be bound to the top level HTML element (`firstNode`) of the corresponding template.

```
Template.foo.events({
  "bar .foo": function() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
});

Template.foo.onRendered(function(){
  Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    var target = this.$(".foo");
    target.trigger("bar");
  }.bind(this));
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/